# PHP _COOKIE var gets undefined (the whole var, not an index)

Tags: php, symfony

We have developed an API with Symfony3 with a MySQL DB for the persistence. We are running this on Wamp (Apache 2.4, MySQL 5.6, PHP 7.0.10).

The API works well most of the time but, sometimes, after a restart, the bootstrap.php.cache throws an exception caused by this notice:

> PHP Notice: Undefined variable: _COOKIE in ....

Here is the entire stack trace coming from the Symfony bowels:

```
14-Feb-2017 07:36:29 UTC PHP Notice: Undefined variable: _COOKIE in C:\xxx\wamp\www\xxx\var\bootstrap.php.cache on line 453
14-Feb-2017 07:36:29 UTC PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 4 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::createRequestFromFactory() must be of the type array, null given, called in C:\xxx\wamp\www\xxx\var\bootstrap.php.cache on line 453 and defined in > > C:\xxx\wamp\www\xxx\var\bootstrap.php.cache:1268
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xxx\wamp\www\xxx\var\bootstrap.php.cache(453): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::createRequestFromFactory(Array, Array, >Array, NULL, Array, Array)
#1 C:\xxx\wamp\www\xxx\web\app.php(15): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::createFromGlobals()
#2 {main}
```

And this is the line where the stack begins:

```
$request = self::createRequestFromFactory($_GET, $_POST, array(), $_COOKIE, $_FILES, $server);
```

It's something strange because, from the stack trace I can know that $_GET, $_POST, and $_FILES are Arrays, but $_COOKIE is not...

Why this var is getting undefined?

Comment: You should post your code , **edit** your question and show us your full Notice warning as well as showing us the line of code that the notice refers to. Then your issue can be answered. You probably forgot a `$` symbol. `_COOKIE` is not a variable, but `$_COOKIE` is.

Comment: It's really strange. Even if you disable some superglobals with `variables_order` the variable itself still exists. You can only reproduce that error with `unset($_COOKIE);`.

Comment: Restarting the Apache's Win service fixes the error. It's really strange because we have the same application running on a lamp and this didn't happened at all...

Comment: [PHP bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73554), maybe?

Comment: Would it be possible this error locates on the value of the parameter `auto_globals_jit`that is **On**?

Comment: @CarlesCapell I've never used that parameter but according to [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-globals-jit) it only affects `$_SERVER` and `$_ENV` and it doesn't disable them anyway, it just uses lazy initialisation on first usage.